# Javascript - Extracting RGB values from pixels

Tags: computer-vision, javascript

I am currently working with a javascript library called [**clmTrackr**](https://github.com/auduno/clmtrackr) which includes the computer vision library [**JsFeat**](http://inspirit.github.io/jsfeat/), and am having problems extracting the RBG value of a pixel in this javascript library.

I have succesfully extracted the values by creating another `<canvas>` and using this code:

```
//  Pixel extraction --RGB
        function cropFaceColor(canvas, locationX, locationY) {
            var idata = canvas.getImageData(locationX,locationY ,1,1);
            var data = idata.data;
            var R = data[0];
            var G = data[1];
            var B = data[2];
            document.getElementById('colorExtraction').innerHTML = R + " " +G + " " + B ;
        }
```

But am wondering if there is a way to accomplish the same goal using only the available functions inside of these libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of research i have realized that there are no built in fnctions for pixel value extraction and the best method i have come across so far has been:

```
var idata = canvas.getImageData(locationX,locationY ,1,1);
            var data = idata.data;
            var R = data[0];
            var G = data[1];
            var B = data[2];
            document.getElementById('colorExtraction').innerHTML = R + " " +G + " " + B ;
```